# Why is laravel view returning array? instead of the value?

Tags: laravel

Here is my controller function

```
public function index()
{
    $currentdate = Carbon::yesterday();
    $totalsales = DB::table('receipts')
        ->whereDate('created_at','=', $currentdate)
        ->where('status','=', 'served')
        ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount_due) as totalsales'))
        ->get();
        // ->first();
        // return $totalsales;
    return view('dashboard.index',compact('totalsales'));
}
```

Here is my View

```
<div class="panel-body">
<h2>{{$totalsales}}</h2>
```

insted of the value itself the view returns an array like this

```
[{"totalsales":"130.00"}]
```

Comment: With get() you will get collection

Comment: @SagarGautam -> so what sould i do?

Comment: If you need only record, you can use `->first()` on otherwise use `->get()`. In above case you can use foreach on `$totalsales`.

Comment: @SagarGautam ok i get i now thank your for the answer :D

Comment: And donot forget to accept if it really help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need just sum of the `amount_due` column so you can use following query.

```
$totalsales = DB::table('receipts')
              ->whereDate('created_at','=', $currentdate)
              ->where('status','=', 'served')
              ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
              ->sum('amount_due');
```

Keep other code same, This will work for you.

Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know there's only one field.

You need to either specify

```
<h2>{{ $totalsales->totalsales }}</h2>
```

or change your query to:

```
    $totalsales = DB::table('receipts')
    ->whereDate('created_at','=', $currentdate)
    ->where('status','=', 'served')
    ->orderBy('created_at','asc')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount_due) as totalsales'))
    ->first()
    ->totalsales;
```

Comment: i tried this one but it showed me this errorCall to undefined method stdClass::value()

Comment: Check my edit.  Instead of ->value('totalsales'), with Query Builder (DB), you need ->totalsales